# "Item with same key" exception; dictionary with enum keys

Tags: c#, exception

I've got a `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` into which I'm inserting a lot of data. The keys are an enum. I keep getting this exception:

> An item with the same key has already been added.

But I don't *see* any dupes, although I suspect some of my enums have the same value. Would that cause a duplicate key error? I thought an enum was a special type, so it's value wouldn't matter.

The exception isn't very helpful...it doesn't tell me which key is tripping the dupe. I'm using an initializer list.

---

**Edit:** Used some regex magic to convert my initializer list into separate `.Add` calls. Found the key, but I'm still not seeing the dupe...

Comment: Just to ask the obvious question: Are you able to debug it visual studio?  If not maybe create an additional check prior to dictionary add operation to see if the key already exists and add throw a more useful exception if it does.

Comment: @lzcd: Well, I couldn't with the initializer list. After I broke it up, it gave me a line #.

Comment: How many values are there in the enum? Are the numeric values specified explicitly or left at default? Is it a [Flags] enum? As Pavel said below, a enum is just an int (by default) or another nunmeric datatype behind the scenes, so sometimes different values (or combinations, in Flags enums) can resolve to the same number.

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan: 256. I'm explicitly setting them, but I've omitted a few. I think they got auto-assigned to existing one. Just a pain-staking process I guess =)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If multiple members of your enum has the same numeric representation that would be the cause of exception.

Comment: Bahh..alright. I'm creating a list of about 256 enum keys, and I haven't numbered all of them yet, so it's auto-assigning them. I think one must have got auto-assigned to one I assigned explicitly.

Comment: try outputing `Enum.GetValues(typeof(yourEnum))' result to console and see if there is duplicates

Comment: Yeah, I found the dupes now. Just going through them one at a time. Thanks! (Had to wait 10 min to accept your answer)

Answer (score 1):

By default the numeric representation of Enums increment so unless you are specifying duplicate values there shouldn't be any.

Try running the below replacing by T with your enum and see if any of the values conflict.

```
return Enum.GetValues(typeof(T));
```

If not then the only alternative I see is that you are using an enum as a key twice.